# WP PHP Loop doesn't display information at end

Tags: php, wordpress, function, if-statement

I have a very simple php loop here (see below) and would like the the two like and dislike counters to appear after the img class "yearofstudy". However the text does not appear after the image. Even if it is placed after the actual HTML.

The Like and Dislike on Comments has to be inside tis function for it to work as it creates a WP loop where they display. Basically, I need help re-arranging this so the like and dislikes appear in the loop but after the image.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I have been staring at this for hours and have looked every online and still yet to find anything.

```
// Add the comment meta (saved earlier) to the comment text 
// You can also output the comment meta values directly in comments template  

add_filter( 'comment_text', 'modify_comment');
function modify_comment( $text ){

    $plugin_url_path = WP_PLUGIN_URL;

    if( $commenttitle = get_comment_meta( get_comment_ID(), 'title', true ) ) {
        $commenttitle = '<strong>' . esc_attr( $commenttitle ) . '</strong><br/>';
        $text = $commenttitle . $text;
    } 

    if( $commentrating = get_comment_meta( get_comment_ID(), 'rating', true ) ) {
        $commentrating = '<p class="comment-rating">    <img src="'. $plugin_url_path .
        '/ExtendComment/images/'. $commentrating . 'star.gif" class="yearofstudy" /></p><br />';


        $text = $text . $commentrating;
        return $text;   

    // LIKE AND DISLIKE ON COMMENTS     
    if(function_exists('like_counter_c')) { like_counter_c('text for like'); }

    if(function_exists('dislike_counter_c')) { dislike_counter_c('text for dislike'); }     
    }

}
```

EDIT:

Although the answers supplied by RecoveringSince2003 does work and makes the like and dislike display, it doesn't allow the functions to appear after the html image yearofstudy. It appears before and this is not what i am after.

For an example see here, make sure you scroll down to see the comments/reviews: http://universitycompare.com/universities/anglia-ruskin-university

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first glance, you have

```
if( $commentrating = get_comment_meta( get_comment_ID(), 'rating', true ) ) {
    $commentrating = '<p class="comment-rating">    <img src="'. $plugin_url_path .
    '/ExtendComment/images/'. $commentrating . 'star.gif" class="yearofstudy" /></p><br />';

    $text = $text . $commentrating;
    return $text;   // <-- terminating the execution

    // following code is never being executed
    // LIKE AND DISLIKE ON COMMENTS     
    if(function_exists('like_counter_c')) { like_counter_c('text for like'); }
    if(function_exists('dislike_counter_c')) { dislike_counter_c('text for dislike'); }     
}
```

So. the `return` statement is terminating the execution of the function and rest of the code after `return` is never being reached. I don't know what/how these function calls are working but if you want to execute these `if(function_exists('like_counter_c'))` lines then move your `return` statement after these lines, something like

```
$text = $text . $commentrating;
if(function_exists('like_counter_c')) { like_counter_c('text for like'); }
if(function_exists('dislike_counter_c')) { dislike_counter_c('text for dislike'); }
return $text;
```

**Update :**

Add some style in your image tag, like (there are other ways too by modifying the `**yearofstudy**` class)

```
<img src="'. $plugin_url_path .
    '/ExtendComment/images/'. $commentrating . 'star.gif" class="yearofstudy" style="float:right" />
```

Comment: Hi @Recovering Since 2003 - Thanks for your help. Although this does work and makes them display, it doesn't allow the functions to appear after the html image yearofstudy. It appears before.

See this link and scroll down to see comments for an example:http://universitycompare.com/universities/anglia-ruskin-university/

Comment: I have checked the update, but still no luck, it appears next to the title and Doesn't move down below the image. Even if it is all floating the right way and position correctly. The PHP above is structuring the html in a different order?

Comment: Try to make changes in `yearofstudy` class in your `css` file, it'll be fine if you know how to make element style.

Comment: I've just decided to move them to the top right and use that instead, I did want them below the image but for now this will do. Thank you very much for your help. Have a look on the same link and see what you think if you want? It's late here ;) Thank you for all your help though. Appreciated!!

Comment: @user1077369, I'm from `Bangladesh` and wish you same :-).